# adding custom fields dynamically to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called List which has many records:

```
class List
 has_many :records
end

class Record

end
```

The table Record has 2 permanent fields: name, email.
Besides these 2 fields, for each List a Record can have 'n' custom fields.

For example: for list1 I add address(text), dob(date) as custom fields.
Then while adding records to list one, each record can have values for address and dob.

Is there any ActiveRecord plugin which provides this type of functionality?
Or else could you share your thoughts on how to model this?

Thanks in advance,
Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look in schemaless database solutions. One that i think is great is [mongoDB](http://mongodb.org).

There is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper) explaining how to use it with rails. Take a look, it works great.

Comment: Sounds good but I wouldn't want dynamic fields be the only reason to move :|

Answer (score 2):

If your custom fields don't need to be real database columns, you could use **serialize**: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000924 You would use it like:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :custom_fields, Hash
end

r = Record.create :custom_fields => {:name => 'John Doe', :birth_date => Date.new(1970,1,1)}

r.custom_fields[:name]
# => 'John Doe'

r.custom_fields[:birth_date]
# => #<Date: 4881175/2,0,2299161>
```

**Pro**: easy to use

**Con**: since the custom fields are not db columns, you can't find records in the db based on their values (e.g. Record.find_by_name('John Doe') does not work)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? [has_magic_columns](http://code.google.com/p/has-magic-columns/). I havn't tested it myself but seems like it can do what you need.

Comment: Does not work with Rails3 though. And the code has not been touched in a while. Cannot find any info on it except for the docs.